# Python: Output on the console comes with Parantheses

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a function "avg" defined in Python (version 3.7.7)  like this:

```
def avg(x,y):
    print("firts input is", x)
    print("second input is", y)
    a = (x + y) / 2.0
    print("average is", a)
    return a

avg(3,4)
```

and it gives me the following output on my console:

('firts input is', 3)
('second input is', 4)
('average is', 3.5)

Why is Python printing the Parantheses and the "," ?
When I just type:

```
print("Hello World!")
```

i dont get the Parantheses ...

Comment: are you sure you are using python 3? this is a common error in python 2.7

Comment: You could try using + sign to join string and variable.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest...

Comment: You are using Python 2.

Comment: When i type python --version i get version 2.7. But when I type python3 --version i get 3.7.7

Comment: Then run your code using python3.

Comment: @chrizzla and how do you run the script? `python script.py`? Then it'll use Python 2.

Comment: thx u r a legend!

Comment: using python3 worked